# Finding Gilgit's Kargah Buddha

Tags: religion, landmarks, pakistan, locate-this, gilgit-baltistan

Wikivoyage says the Kargah Buddha carving is near [Gilgit](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gilgit#See):

> Located on a rock near Kargah Nullah (ravine), 10 km. from Gilgit town is a beautiful rock engraving of Buddha from 7th century A.D.

Wikipedia has [an article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kargah_Buddha) but no coordinates.

Google Maps does not know it.

What are the latitude/longitude of the Kargah Buddha?

[image: Kargah Buddha]
*Credit: [Mountainloverk2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ABuddha_at_Kargah_Gilgit.jpg), [CC-BY-SA-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)*

Comment: @pnuts: How did you find these coordinates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kargah Buddha is located approximately at: [35° 54' 38.30" N  74° 15' 43.20" E](http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=35.910638&ln=74.261999&z=4&k=2). You should be able to spot it if you are around there.

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com.sa/maps/@35.9104293,74.262569,451m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) is not high-res enough to be able to see it in the satellite view, I guess that's also due to the angle of the carved Buddha image, anyhow Google Maps includes a [photo of the Kargah Buddha](https://www.google.com.sa/maps/@35.911578,74.261536,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m5!1e2!3m3!1s98575105!2e1!3e10?hl=en) when pointing the map around there and it points to the mentioned coordinates above.

Sources: [panoramio.com 1](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/23123610), [panoramio.com 2](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/98574760), [Google Maps photos](https://www.google.com.sa/maps/@35.911578,74.261536,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m5!1e2!3m3!1s98575105!2e1!3e10?hl=en)